# Time reversal and basis independence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry

It is generally assumed that to time reverse a state, one just takes the complex conjugate of the wave function.

This is apparently not basis-independent.

For example, if we take $|\psi_0 \rangle $ as a basis vector in some basis, then the time reversal operator $K$ acts on it as

$K|\psi_0 \rangle  = | \psi_0 \rangle $.

Now let us take $|\phi_0 \rangle = e^{-i \theta } |\psi_0 \rangle $, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$K|\psi_0 \rangle  = K (e^{i \theta } | \phi_0 \rangle ) = e^{-i \theta } | \phi_0 \rangle \neq |\psi_0 \rangle $.

Therefore, the simple complex conjugate recipe is not basis-independent. How can this be reconciled with the idea that it represents time reversal?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not basis independent, it holds in the position representation (for time-independent Hamiltonians). In a different basis the time-reversal operator takes a different form (like any operator, although this operator is anti-linear rather than linear).

Comment: Of course an operator takes a different form in a different basis. But, its action should not change. Its action should not vary from basis to basis.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean... In a different basis the time reversal operator does not act as complex conjugation anymore.

Comment: Did you mean to ask how it can be that if $|\psi\rangle$ and $\alpha|\psi\rangle$ represent the same state, but if $K|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ and $\alpha$ is non-real then $K(\alpha|\psi\rangle) \ne \alpha|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: I mean, in the basis of $|\psi_0 \rangle$, $|\psi_0 \rangle $ is a real vector, and therefore, according to the complex conjugation recipe, i get $K|\psi_0\rangle = |\psi_0 \rangle$. However, in the basis of $|\phi_0 \rangle$, $|\psi_0\rangle $ is not real, and therefore, according to the recipe, $K |\psi_0 \rangle \neq |\psi_0 \rangle$. In different basis, you get different results! But the basic idea of physics is that any result should be coordinate-independent.

Comment: Change of basis means $U |\psi_0\rangle$ *and* $U K U^{-1} $ In this new basis $T \neq K$.